# Error: iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.'

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect FTC's fmltc(https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/fmltc) with Google Cloud and train the datasets for object recognition. I am able to login to fmltc and immediately I got the the error of:
Error: iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.'

I am new to Google Cloud. I googled the error and I am not able to solve the problem. I am also following the instructions of ReadMe.md from https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/fmltc carefully.

I searched and found out "storage.buckets.get" is a permission. I could not find which other role can grant this permission since this service account is already "Computer Storage Admin". I don't know if any other role is related to "storage". Appreciate if anyone could give me a hint on this.

Secondly, I tried to create the bucket "XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com". I got the following:

A bucket name can only use dots (.) to form a valid domain name (e.g., example.com). If you haven't verified that you're authorized to use this domain, you'll have to do so to create this bucket.

The error makes me think I should not do this. Maybe I need to create a kind of Google Cloud Storage bucket that I can assign the permission of storage.buckets.get to. But then I don't know how a random bucket connects to "xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com" service account. Really appreciate it if anyone can share advice and opinion on this error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several IAM roles with the permission `storage.buckets.get`:

- Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
- Storage Legacy Bucket Writer
- Storage Legacy Bucket Owner
- Storage Admin

[IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

You mention the role **Computer Storage Admin**, which does exist. Do you mean **Storage Admin**?

If you have the correct role and you receive an error about no permission, you have probably **specified the wrong bucket name**.

You mentioned the error:

```
Error: iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

`iam.gserviceaccount.com` is not a valid service account email address. Double check what you are specifying and the error message.

Comment: The error starts with: xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. xxxx is a unique team name.                              I realized the 3 Storage Legacy Bucket xxxxx and Storage Admin are associated with storage.buckets.get. I found these four roles in Cloud Storage/bucket. I add the roles in the main project bucket, the same error still exists. I have couple other buckets, but I don't have the xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com in the bucket. Shall I create a bucket for it and then assign the 4 roles for it?

Comment: I can only assign the roles of Storage Legacy Bucket.XXX in Cloud Storage/Buckets. And the error still exists. So I went to IAM & Admin, and I tried to assign "Permissions for project "XXX". Inside the Principal "xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com" I couldn't find any Storage Legacy Bucket.XXX. Therefore I assigned the closest related to Storage role as "Computer Storage Admin". It is confusing and it seems the roles list in "IAM & Admin" is different in "Cloud Storage/Buckets". Appreciate any advise.

Comment: @Skippy 1) Double check the bucket name 2) Double check which credentials you are using. 3) Show me a screenshot (in your question) of "Computer Storage Admin". That role does not exist.